Physical Significance of Torque
When we say that Net Torque on a rigid body about some point, say O is zero,then what do we practically mean here? A body can either rotate about a particular point or it may not rotate at all (Please note that I am not taking here into account,the translatory effect of force) but we can always find more than one point about which torque is not zero and many more points about which torque is zero,although the body is rotating about only one single point
Edit:I would reframe my problem so that becomes less ambiguous
Consider an object rotation about an axis perpendicular to the plane containing the object(The axis is not a fixed hinge or support to which the block is attached).The axis intersects the body at point O.
Suppose,I take 2 points A and B such that Torque on the body about A is zero and Torque on the about B is non zero.Now the torque about the axis is defined as the torque about O and it's non zero.
Now my query is:
If torque about O is non zero,there is rotational effect of Force and hence the body is rotating about O.The torque about A is zero and the body is not rotating about A. But Torque about B is non zero,yet the body is not performing Rotation about B,so what does the torque about B signify??


If torque about O is non zero,there is rotational effect of Force and hence the body is rotating about O.

Maybe, maybe not.   We can say that the angular momentum about that point is changing.   Angular momentum does not have to be rotation.
Here's an example:

(We will ignore gravity and other objects).   Before the force is applied, the box is at rest.
When $F$ is applied, the force is in-line with A (the center-of-mass) of the object.   As such, the object does not start rotating.   It just accelerates to the right.
The torque from $F$ about $A$ is zero since it passes through the point.   This tells us that the angular momentum of the system about $A$ is unchanging.
The torque from $F$ about $B$ is non-zero.   This tells us that the angular momentum of the system about $B$ is changing.   This can include a change in linear velocity, not just a change in the rotation of the object.
The (possibly non-zero) angular momentum of a non-rotating particle is described at hyperphysics.   $L = mvr \sin(\theta)$. As the box accelerates, the velocity along a line that does not go through the point is non-zero, so the angular momentum about that point increases.

(+1) If the cube is rotating in water, will it also move forward (gaining linear momentum) due to its own rotation?

That would introduce lots of forces on the cube from the water and make things very difficult to analyze.   I'd say that should be asked as a separate question.   Do cubes rotating in water normally move in one direction?
